# How to Configure a VNC Server (TigerVNC) in Ubuntu server 22.10 without GUI

Tags: server, vnc

The GUI is currently loading XFCE. But I need to start VNC session without any GUI...

Here is my default config in file ~/.vnc/xstartup

```
#!/bin/sh

# Start up the standard system desktop
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

/usr/bin/startxfce4

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
x-window-manager &
```

1. **What do I need to do so that when starting a VNC session, only the terminal would be loaded?**

(What I need to change in "~/.vnc/xstartup" file?). And if you could, write an example of file, please.

2. How can I make changes for all users?

Answer (score 0):

this is way to solve it.

Just use the default config `/etc/X11/Xtigervnc-session` as described here

https://askubuntu.com/a/1443638/1706918

:-)